# In-browser HTML editor for tables?

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I'm developing a website that publishes scientific articles, not as PDF but as HTML. As a input tool for the editorial team, we use TinyMCE for normal text plus a couple of custom plugins for footnotes and citations. But we are not really happy with TinyMCEs table controls. Everything but the most simple tables take way to long to write. Are there any specialized table editing tools for the browser out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**CKEditor**](http://ckeditor.com/demo) provides a *bit* more convenience through its table dialogs, and a number of nice context menu functions like those you would expect from a word processor. Check it out, maybe it already is improvement enough.

That said, editing tables in web browsers is still a pain, no matter what you use. It's kind of inherent because the basic HTML editing capabilties all WYSIWYG editors use are provided by the browser.

Whenever tables are needed in a project, I tend to build a "static" plug-in that allows to enter table data through a fixed grid, and set dimensions using text fields. That is nowhere near WYSIWYG table editing, though, of course.

Comment: @snowflake a downvote for an answer that lists all the options? Seriously?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this also

http://www.impressivewebs.com/html-table-code-generator/